# Bootstrap alert alert- success not working

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, alert

So I used these  bootstrap alerts

Problem- My web page is an easy signup page designed with CSS and HTML. when I use signup button and when the logic works correctly it show the text success but not showing in the correct alert.[the success alert should be shown in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO0J9.png)

```js
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var text = request.responseText;
            if (text == "success"){
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = text;
                document.getElementById("msg").className = "bi bi-check2-circle fs-5";
                document.getElementById("alertdiv").className ="alert alert-success";
                document.getElementById("msgdiv").className = "d-block";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = text;
                document.getElementById("msgdiv").className = "d-block";
            }
        }
    }

    
    request.open("POST","signUpProcess.php",true);
    request.send(form);

}
```

```html
 <div class="col-12 p-3">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col-6 d-none d-lg-block background "></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 " id="signUpBox">
                    <div class="row g-2">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <p class="title2">Create New Account</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 d-none" id="msgdiv">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="alertdiv">
                                    <i class="bi bi-x-octagon-fill fs-5" id="msg"></i>
                                        
                                    
                                </div>
```

I have test my code over and over again but the error shows every time

Comment: Have you verified it actually went into your if- and not the else-branch? (Just because the text you see rendered as HTML might spell "success", does not necessarily mean that `text` contained _exactly_ that, maybe you have extra whitespace around the value.)

Comment: For debugging try to add console.log(`"${text}"`) after you receive a text from the request. Also, add console.log inside the if block to make sure it's executed.

Comment: `text.trim() == "success"`

Comment: yeah i have tried that something is wrong in the index.php but i cant find it